# how to check that a time difference is equal to an interval of time in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Both of these methods are part of a class I created as an invoice generator.
My issue only involves these two methods but let me know if I need to show rest of code.
I am having a problem checking whether or not the difference between **startTime** and **endTime** is equal to **self.actualJobHrs**. I used **datetime.strptime()** to return a time formatted string. I have tested to see if the time difference between **startTime** and **endTime** is correct but the **if endTime - startTime == self.actualJobHrs:** is not working as it should. I think this because **self.actualJobHrs** isn't in same format as **endTime - startTime** so condition is always false. Iv'e experimented with many ways to get this to work properly but haven't been able to crack it. Any suggestions or possible solutions to this will be much appreciated...Thanks!

```
def set_actualJobHrs(self):

    while True:

        print("Enter the number of hrs on job in [hr:min] format")
        try:
            self.actualJobHrs = datetime.strptime(input("Enter job hrs: "), "%H:%M")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("job hrs must be in [hr:min] format")


def set_hrsAtSite(self):


    while True:
        print("Enter the start and end time for hrs at site in [hr:min (AM/PM)] format")

        try:
            startTime = datetime.strptime(input("Enter the start time: "), "%H:%M %p")

            endTime = datetime.strptime(input("Enter the end time: "), "%H:%M %p")

            if endTime - startTime == self.actualJobHrs:
                self.hrsAtSite = f"{startTime.strftime('%I:%M %p')} " + "to" + \
                                 f" {endTime.strftime('%I:%M %p')}"
                break
            else: 
                print("Start and end time of job doesn't match hrs of job")
                

        except ValueError:
            print("start and end time must be in [hr:min (AM/PM)] format")
```

**found a solution to the problem**

```
 def set_hrsAtSite(self):

        jobHrs = datetime.time(self.actualJobHrs).hour
        jobMin = datetime.time(self.actualJobHrs).minute
        while True:
            print("Enter the start and end time for hrs at site in [hr:min (AM/PM)] format")

            try:
                startTime = datetime.strptime(input("Enter the start time: "), "%H:%M %p")
                endTime = datetime.strptime(input("Enter the end time: "), "%H:%M %p")
                timeDiff = endTime - startTime
                if timedelta(hours=jobHrs, minutes=jobMin) <= timeDiff:
                    self.hrsAtSite = f"{startTime.strftime('%I:%M %p')} " + "to" + \
                                     f" {endTime.strftime('%I:%M %p')}"
                    break
                else:
                    print("Start and end time of job doesn't match hrs of job")


            except ValueError:
                print("start and end time must be in [hr:min (AM/PM)] format")
```

Comment: IIUC, `actualJobHrs` represents a duration, so the type I'd use is timedelta (instead of datetime). That is also the type you get if you subtract datetime objects from each other. Once you have same types, the comparison works.

Comment: One more note, the `==` compares for *exact* equality. That might not exactly be what you want, e.g. you might want to compare only full hours or use a less/greater equal comparison instead.

Comment: Thanks  FObersteiner, had to read in between the lines to implement what you were saying but I figured it out. I appreciate the advice.